# Index values greater than X?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I index all the values greater than 50?

```
150
60
50
70
100
200
```

Comment: Match will only return one number, the relative location of the match.  If you are going to use anything but `0` in the third criterion then your data must be sorted in ascending order.  The `50` is in the third location in the data set relatively so not matter what that is what it will return.

Comment: In the end what do you expect as an outcome? MATCH may not be the correct formula.

Comment: Yeah i expected it would tell me how many matches it found (: my bad.

Comment: Note also that if the third parameter is -1, then it will find the smallest value that is greater than or equal to the search value. Similarly, if it's 1 it will find the largest value that is less than or equal to the search value. So even if the list were sorted, all three would still return the same result.

Comment: Reworked the question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want the list in the same order as the reference list then:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))>50),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

---

If you want them in numerical order then we can get rid of INDEX:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))>50),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

To make descending(Largest to smallest) change the `15` to `14`

[image]

---

These are larger than it needs to be for a fixed data set.

Array type formulas need to be limited to the data set. If your data set is fixed you can replace both `$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` with `$A$1:$A$6` and it will be a little smaller.

The `$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` finds and sets a range starting at A1 and ending in the last cell with a number in Column A.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure it out. - This is huge.

Comment: It is larger than it needs to be for a fixed data set.  Array type formulas need to be limited to the data set.  If your data set is fixed you can replace both `$A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))` with `$A$1:$A$6` and it will be a little smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can just return the values greater than 50 is with this array formula (assuming your list is `A1:A20`):

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$20,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$20>50,ROW($A$1:$A$20)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROWS($A$1:A1)))`

(enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

And just wrap `IFERROR([formula],"")` around it to hide the `#NUM` error that occurs when there are no more matches.  If you want to return the values from the bottom to top, just change `SMALL` to `LARGE` in the formula.

[image]